# Align decimal points in sql server reporting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is this possible to align decimal point to centre and also align the whole field in centre as well.

[image]

If i align the column to right then decimal points are in the middle but is it possible to have all this in the middle as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way of doing what you want. Try setting the right padding to a high value to push the values toward the middle.

Comment: it does work but the column heading looks weird because of padding. Is there any way to set padding just for detail cell and not for heading?

Comment: Isn't the heading in a separate field? You should be able to set their properties separately.

Comment: everything is in tablix

Comment: yes you are right sorry ignore my comments, i was clicking in the cell instead of selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try "#,###.??". However, you can't eliminate decimal point "." for numbers that don't have fractions.