# Measure the width of characters to add space to align decimal points in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

My questions are simple: **How can I align decimal points? How can I measure the width of characters in an SSRS report?**

The story is...

I am now formatting currencies in a Table in my SSRS report.

```
Formatted         Value
      -           0
     $0.00        0.00444
     $0.62        0.618
($5,012.00)       -5012
```

1. Zeroes are represented as a hyphen, aligned at the dollar digit place.
2. Non-zeroes are shown with a decimal point, and two digits to the right, and at least one digit to the left, and the dollar sign.
3. A comma separates every group of three digits.
4. Negative values are printed in red (not demonstrated above), inside a pair of brackets. A hyphen for the negative sign is not needed.

In MS Excel, a very simple format string `$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00);-_._0_0_)` gives me the format wanted. I've tried it in the SSRS report but it fails as the `_` doesn't [add space as it does in MS Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4). I have managed to format the negatives in red by setting the color property with an `IIF` function, but failed to put the hyphen for zeroes and the positive values in the correct position.

According to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686789/align-decimal-points-in-sql-server-reporting), I believe there's no "simple" format string to obtain the format. It suggest adjusting right padding, so now I try to measure the width. The width may vary if different font properties apply. Therefore, I wonder if there is any function that returns text width, [as there is in TeX/LaTeX typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length/37294#37294).

Alternatives that do not measure the width but can still align decimal points are also welcome.

Comment: Let's assume all of the ten digits has the same width. But you're a genius if you do not need this assumption!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and tackled it by having two columns - one for dollars (right aligned) and one for cents (left aligned, including decimal).  Remove the middle border and... voila!

You can use Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML" in your visibility expressions to show/hide columns for your Excel export.

Comment: Thanks. When I export to Excel, no single cell will contain an amount, so it will be inconvenient if one wants to extract the amounts using Excel. Anyway, this idea is clever and simple enough to get the layout wanted.

Comment: I edited the answer on how to handle the Excel issue!